# dumpsys battery in Termux

Tags: adb, battery, termux, dumpsys

I am trying to get battery info in Termux.

I granted `android.permission.DUMP` and `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` via ADB for `com.termux` (Termux app)

Then I opened Termux and types in `/system/bin/dumpsys battery`. It displays this error message:

```
Can't find service: battery
```

and exits with code 0.

I can confirm that I can get those info via ADB using the same command (e.g. getting battery level with `/system/bin/dumpsys battery | grep level`)

Am I missing some permissions for Termux app? Or are there some more fixes? Please help.

Edit: I am aware of the existence of `termux-battery-status` command in Termux. It's output is not too informative. So I will not accept answers telling me to use the command.

Comment: It's restricted by SELinux. Apps cannot access `u:object_r:battery_service:s0` context.

Comment: So this has no workaround?